# Range of 32 bit unit C programming language

Tags: c, numbers, int, overflow

I'm currently studying C programming language by following the book "C primer plus".

In the section on overflow, the author states

> minimum range for long is `–2,147,483,647 to 2,147,483,647`,
>   corresponding to a 32-bit unit.

I was wondering, shouldn't the max value for a 32 bit unit be `2,147,483,648` and not `2,147,483,647` as stated by the author?

I have also seen [on tutorial point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm) that the range for a 32 bit unit is `–2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647`. I'm extremely confused.

---

Also, when I run the code

```
int i = 2147483647;
printf("%d %d %d\n", i, i+1, i+2);
```

I got the result `2147483647 -2147483648 -2147483647`, which support that the range of 32 bit unit is `–2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647`. So which one is correct?

PS - I have studied two's complement system previous, and from what I can remember, the max number should always be the `-(min number) + 1`, so from the two's complement system, I was thinking that `–2,147,483,647 to 2,147,483,648` is more likely to be correct. But the `printf` above seem to support `–2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647`, and both are different to what the author stated `–2,147,483,647 to 2,147,483,647`.

Comment: It depends on the internal representation of integers. If to consider  2's complement  then you are right but not in p.s.:)

Comment: This is the minimum range specified in the Standard (-2147483647 -- 2147483647) for `long int`, not the range that can be stored in 32 bits; and remember that C allows for two's complement, one's complement, and sign and magnitude representations for integer types.

Comment: hi @VladFromMoscoe, thank you for the comment. So there are some instance of internal representation of integers that dont use 2's complement? how popular are those alternative representations?

Comment: @DavidBowling, ah, that make sense. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: @Thor The C Standard accepts three kinds of internal representations: "sign and magnitude", "two’s complement" and "ones’ complement"

Comment: "**minimum range** for long is –2,147,483,647 to 2,147,483,647," is correct.  Your example of  `–2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647` does _not_ contradict that.

Comment: "how popular are those alternative representations" --> they are not popular at all, yet because of their historic possibility the C language and various modern optimizations consider them.  FWIW, floating point uses a sign-magnitude as part of is significand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

32-bits of memory can encode, **at most**, 2<sup>32</sup> different values.

C integers consists of 3 parts: sign bit, values bits and rarely padding bits.  For this answer, assume the number of padding bits is zero.

C supports 3 integer encodings: 2's complement, 1's complement, sign magnitude.

A 32-bit integer then has the range of

1. 2's complement: `[–2,147,483,648 ... 2,147,483,647]`  Most common by far
2. 1's complement: `[–2,147,483,647 ... 2,147,483,647]`  1 smaller range than 2's
3. sign magnitude: `[–2,147,483,647 ... 2,147,483,647]`  1 smaller range than 2's

All 3 then meet the C requirement for a `long`:

> Their implementation-defined values shall be **equal or greater in magnitude** (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign.
>   - minimum value for an object of type `long int` `LONG_MIN` `-2147483647`
>   - maximum value for an object of type `long int` `LONG_MAX` `+2147483647` C11dr 
>   §5.2.4.2.1 1

Note that `long` as well as `int` could be 64-bit and have a much wider range.

---

> I was wondering, shouldn't the max value for a 32 bit unit be 2,147,483,648

2,147,483,648 is not compatible with a 32-bit [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) as that would take 33 bits.

---

Avoid integer overflow in C as it is *undefined behavior* (UB).  OP's text output is not definitive.

```
int i = 2147483647;   // v----v----- UB
printf("%d %d %d\n", i, i+1, i+2);
```

Instead print the min/max based on `<limits.h>`:

```
printf("int  min:%d max:%d\n", INT_MIN, INT_MAX);
printf("long min:%ld max:%ld\n", LONG_MIN, LONG_MAX);
```

---

Even if OP's minimum integer is –2,147,483,648, that does not mean that it is the minimum value on all implementations.  The C spec only requires –2,147,483,647 or less.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. It cleared up a lot of confusion. Really appreciate it!! :)

Answer (score 0):

–2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 plus ZERO. Simply put, you forgot to count the ZERO.

Comment: "you forgot ..." is likely not true.